# Is there a service for HTTP redirection with static IP?

Tags: http, redirect, static-ip-address

I have a requirement in which I need to access a particular server from an already defined static IP address in order to be able to access the provided content.

That means, any IP address -> URL redirection -> Server.

The URL redirection server must have an static IP address, and all other accesses from other IP addresses must need to be forwarded by it.

I know I could write little code to take a request and forward it using any programming language. But maybe, there's already a service which I can purchase for doing the job.

I've been looking around the web and nothing seems to be clear about what's the name of what I'm looking for.

Is kind of like a proxy, but I cannot find the right solution for this scenario.

Can you help me out with this given some indication? Or is it the best way just to implement the forwarding logic myself and hosted somewhere on the internet with the defined static IP address?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You may wan to look at http://www.rackspace.com/cloud/load-balancing/ they give you an IP address that is then forwarded to wherever  you wan it to go.

Comment: try not to resurrect old questions. It's unlikely the person asking this question is still trying to solve this particular problem. Also, I think Rackspace loadbalancers will only load balance against Rackspace load balancers not to wherever (although I'm not certain about that)